# Adjusting scaleX and scaleY of Div with HTML5 Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Experimenting with JQuery and HTML5 for a college assignment at the moment. I would like to update the css values of the div when the slider is moved.

HTML

```
Scale<input id="slider" type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
```

Currently this is my script:

```
$("#slider").change(function(){
    size = $("#slider").val();
    console.log("Size: " + size);
    //Update the size of box while dragging
    b1.css({
        "-webkit-transform":"scaleX"+size/10,
        "-webkit-transform":"scaleY"+size/10
    });
});
```

It works however the values do not seem to be updating in my CSS and I am guessing it is because I am assigning them incorrectly.

Does anyone have a solution as to how I can fix the problem?

JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/JQ7vD/

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You forgot parenthesis: `"-webkit-transform":"scaleX("+size/10+")"`

Comment: That solved the issue @Zeaklous. However for some reason both values are still not being updated. Only the `-webkit-transform:scaleY`...Is there anyway to simultaneously increment them?

Comment: You're currently overwriting your `scaleX` with your `scaleY`, you need this: `"-webkit-transform": "scaleX(" + size/10 + ") scaleY(" + size/10 + ")"`.

Comment: @thirtydot Solved! Much thanks, answer and I will mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was that you forgot your parenthesis before and after the scale value. To make it scale both the X and Y, however, you need to combine the jQuery lines into one, i.e.

```
b1.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "scaleX(" + size / 10 + ") scaleY(" + size / 10 + ")"
});
```

This is because if you have them in separate lines then the second one will always override the first because it does so in CSS. Take the following example

```
#image {
    background:url('/exampleImage.jpg');
    background:red;
}
```

The background would be red, not the image declared first. To support all browsers you need to include the browser prefixes in the jQuery as well

Answer (score 1):

```
b1.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale3d(' + size/10 + ',' + size/10 + ',1)',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale3d(' + size/10 + ',' + size/10 + '1)',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale3d(' + size/10 + ',' + size/10 + ',1)',
        'transform': 'scale3d(' + size/10 + ',' + size/10 + ',1)'
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ7vD/4/

Comment: You don't want to be scaling the `z`.